# glossaries use of sort key

Tags: glossaries, sorting

after reading the manual of the glossaries packages I was under the impression that when you use the sort key that it would be sorted alphabetically according to the text given in this sort key. However, this MWE does not achieve this (in reality of course I have much more symbols so I really need the automatic sorting and it would take to long to define them in the correct order when I define them)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{thetab}
{%
name={$\Theta_{b}$},
description={temperature coefficient for b},
sort=temperature coefficient for b ,
}

\newglossaryentry{thetaa}
{%
 name={$\Theta_{a}$},
 description={temperature coefficient for a},
 sort=temperature coefficient for a,
}

\newglossaryentry{thetade}
{%
name={$\Theta_{de}$},
description={temperature coefficient for de},
sort=temperature coefficient for de,
}

\newglossaryentry{thetaOP}
{%
name={$\Theta_{OP}$},
description={temperature coefficient for OP},
sort=temperature coefficient for op,
}

\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossary[sort=standard,title={List of Symbols}]

\chapter{first chapter}
\lipsum

testing \gls{thetab} and \gls{thetaa} 

some more references \gls{thetade} and \gls{thetaOP}

\end{document}
```

which gives this result:

[image]

where I would have expected this order if sorted alphabetically:

temperature coeffcient for a

temperature coeffcient for b

temperature coeffcient for de

temperature coeffcient for OP

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think that the string for the "sort" key needs to be in braces, like the other argument values.

Comment: @barbara: you are probably right that it is better to put them in braces, but I have tested it and it does not change the order of the sorting unfortunately

Comment: did you make sure that `makeindex` ran again before you ran the last iteration of latex?  (that's the same order of steps that would be involved if you made a change to the sort of an index; the `glossaries` package takes advantage of the `makeindex` mechanism, which is a multi-step process.)

Comment: Remove the spaces: `sort={temperaturecoefficientfora}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ingrid is using the noidx option, which means that the sorting is done by tex and not an external tool.

Comment: @Ulrike indeed I am not using makeindex since I am actually using two different glossaries (one for acronyms and one for symbols) so using the option of letting Tex do it seemed to work better for me, except for the sorting issue which you have solve for me, thanks!

Comment: @Ingrid: makeglossaries/makeindex/xindy can handle two different glossaries without problem -- and they are better (and faster) with sorting. As the manual says: sorting with tex is "but it’s slow and it
doesn’t work well for extended Latin alphabets". With makeglossaries your example worked directly (after change of the \make and \print commands naturally).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- thanks.  i'm still operating with tex live 2012.  it's rather less functional.  (but removing the spaces wasn't necessary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `standard` sort order isn't working, but it works fine if you switch to `letter`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{thetab}
{%
name={$\Theta_{b}$},
description={temperature coefficient for b},
sort=temperature coefficient for b,
}

\newglossaryentry{thetaa}
{%
 name={$\Theta_{a}$},
 description={temperature coefficient for a},
 sort=temperature coefficient for a,
}

\newglossaryentry{thetade}
{%
name={$\Theta_{de}$},
description={temperature coefficient for de},
sort=temperature coefficient for de,
}

\newglossaryentry{thetaOP}
{%
name={$\Theta_{OP}$},
description={temperature coefficient for OP},
sort=temperature coefficient for op,
}

\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossary[sort=letter,title={List of Symbols}]

\chapter{first chapter}
\lipsum

testing \gls{thetab} and \gls{thetaa} 

some more references \gls{thetade} and \gls{thetaOP}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of glossary]

Incidentally, if you want to sort by a different field (the `description` in this case), you can redefine the hook that sets the value of the `sort` key. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\glsprestandardsort}[3]{%
 \protected@edef#1{\glsentrydesc{#3}}%
}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{thetab}
{%
name={$\Theta_{b}$},
description={temperature coefficient for b}
}

\newglossaryentry{thetaa}
{%
 name={$\Theta_{a}$},
 description={temperature coefficient for a}
}

\newglossaryentry{thetade}
{%
name={$\Theta_{de}$},
description={temperature coefficient for de}
}

\newglossaryentry{thetaOP}
{%
name={$\Theta_{OP}$},
description={temperature coefficient for OP}
}

\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossary[sort=letter,title={List of Symbols}]

\chapter{first chapter}
\lipsum

testing \gls{thetab} and \gls{thetaa} 

some more references \gls{thetade} and \gls{thetaOP}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

A better redefinition of `\glsprestandardsort` is:

```
\glssanitizesorttrue

\renewcommand{\glsprestandardsort}[3]{%
  \glsfieldfetch{#3}{desc}{#1}%
  \glsdosanitizesort
}
```

(This no longer needs the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` part.)

The `\glssanitizesorttrue` bit will make `\glsdosanitizesort` apply `\@onelevel@sanitize` to the sort field, which will allow commands like `\si` to appear in the description (but it will apply the same logic as `makeindex` and treat `\si` as the sequence of characters `\`, `s` and `i`).

The second argument of `\glsprestandardsort` is the glossary type, so you can test it to vary the way the `sort` field is set according to the glossary. For example:

```
\renewcommand{\glsprestandardsort}[3]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{main}}%
  {%
    \glsfieldfetch{#3}{desc}{#1}%
  }{}%
  \glsdosanitizesort
}
```

Comment: thanks, this last solution is indeed much more elegant and achieves what I want to do much easier. It works in the MWE, but in my large document, it gives errors as sometimes I am using \si{} in the description which apparently is no longer allowed

Comment: @Ingrid updated my answer to allow for `\si`.

Comment: thanks works like a charm. I am encountering another problem though. I am also having a list of acronyms and now they are also sorted based on the description whereas I would like this list to be sorted alphabetically based on their acronym. Is it possible with this method to have two different methods for each list?

Comment: @Ingrid Yes, I've updated my answer to test for the glossary type.

Comment: thanks for your very quick reply's. They are really appreciated since I am running against a deadline! I clearly still have a lot to learn as I can currently only apply the standard stuff but am clueless about the stuff behind the scenes which is of course necessary when you want to do the cool stuff

Answer (score 2):

Remove the spaces in the sort key values:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{thetab}
{%
name={$\Theta_{b}$},
description={temperature coefficient for b},
sort=temperaturecoefficientforb,
}

\newglossaryentry{thetaa}
{%
 name={$\Theta_{a}$},
 description={temperature coefficient for a},
 sort=temperaturecoefficientfora,
}

\newglossaryentry{thetade}
{%
name={$\Theta_{de}$},
description={temperature coefficient for de},
sort=temperaturecoefficientforde,
}

\newglossaryentry{thetaOP}
{%
name={$\Theta_{OP}$},
description={temperature coefficient for OP},
sort=temperaturecoefficientforop,
}

\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossary[sort=standard,title={List of Symbols}]

\chapter{first chapter}
\lipsum

testing \gls{thetab} and \gls{thetaa}

some more references \gls{thetade} and \gls{thetaOP}

\end{document}
```

[image]