# Nomenclature with glossaries and xindy forget some symbols

Tags: glossaries, xindy, glossaries-extra

I would like to create a large nomenclature thanks to `glossaries` packages. I also would like to sort the element of the nomenclature by symbols, because I found it easier when you are looking for information. 
And I also want to use `xindy` because I will have to deal with accented characters.

My problem arrives with the fact that my nomenclature will be very large and some symbols might be identical (at least for now). This kind of sorting with `xindy` creates a problem: the repeated `symbols` do not appear in the nomenclature (here `fbis` for example). I found a way to sanitize the sorting on this [page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304092/glossaries-use-of-sort-key), but this solution implies to sort by description which is not desirable in my case.

Therefore, I am looking for a solution to keep: `glossaries` and `xindy` sorting by symbol's `name` even if there is redundant symbols.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nonumberlist,nomain, xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{Nomenclature}

\makeglossaries 

% To improve the sorting by description, otherwise when symbols are the same the second is not printed.
%\glssanitizesorttrue
%\renewcommand{\glsprestandardsort}[3]{%
%   \glsfieldfetch{#3}{desc}{#1}%
%   \glsdosanitizesort
%}

\newglossaryentry{xi}{type=symbols,
    name={\ensuremath{ \xi }},  
    description={space variable} }

\newglossaryentry{xii}{type=symbols,
    name={\ensuremath{ \xi_i }},    
    description={discretized space variable} }

\newglossaryentry{f}{type=symbols,
    name={\ensuremath{ f }},    
    description={function of space variable} }

\newglossaryentry{fbis}{type=symbols,
    name={\ensuremath{ f }},    
    description={another function of space variable} }

\newglossaryentry{fi}{type=symbols,
    name={\ensuremath{ f_i }},  
    description={discretized function} }

\begin{document}
    A document that contains \gls{f}, \gls{xi}, \gls{fi} and \gls{xii}, but also a second \gls{fbis}. 
    You can notice that `fbis` is missing in the nomenclature.

    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you add a sort key?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It was my first attempt, but if the sort keys are the same my problem occurs ; and manage different sort keys for the same symbols in a very large list of symbols is becoming a nightmare (how to sure you haven't forgot one, except by checking one by one?). Therefore, I think that having an automatic sorting by symbols worth it.

Comment: Sorry but if you use the same "sort" key (be it is the name or a real sort key)  on different items, what should xindy do? Roll a dice? Also it doesn't make much sense to have lots of items all referring to $f$ but with slightly different description. What use has this for a user of the index? Why don't you change the description so that it fits for all? Like "used for various variants of the function of the space variable".

Comment: xindy merges entries with duplicate sort values. If you removed `nonumberlist` and insert `\newpage` before `\gls{fbis}` you'll find that the `f` entry has two locations: page 1 (from `\gls{f}`) and page 2 (from `\gls{fbis}`).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I understand your purpose. I don't want to keep all of the symbols identicals. I will try to change them to have as few as possible identical. But in order to know whose that have to be changed, I prefer to print them rather than look into the code. I don't except `xindy` nor `glossaries` to roll a dice, it would be a terrible sorting solution otherwise; but maybe it can concatenate the fields `description` to the sorting keys when two keys are identical for different entries.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, Yes, this is true: they appearing on page 1 and 2, but for the same description. And I assume that is due to the fact that `f` and `fbis` are sharing the same sorting key. Therefore, I wonder if there a way to ask `glossaries` to create a sorting key which would be the concatenation of the fields `name` + `description`. In such way, the sorting key would be always different, and the problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\glsprestandardsort` so that it appends the description to the sort value:

```
\renewcommand{\glsprestandardsort}[3]{%
   \glsfieldfetch{#3}{sortvalue}{\tmpA}%
   \glsfieldfetch{#3}{desc}{\tmpB}%
   \edef#1{\expandonce\tmpA\expandonce\tmpB}%
   \glsdosanitizesort
}
```

Here's the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nomain,nonumberlist,xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{Nomenclature}

\makeglossaries 

\renewcommand{\glsprestandardsort}[3]{%
   \glsfieldfetch{#3}{sortvalue}{\tmpA}%
   \glsfieldfetch{#3}{desc}{\tmpB}%
   \edef#1{\expandonce\tmpA\expandonce\tmpB}%
   \glsdosanitizesort
}

\newglossaryentry{xi}{type=symbols,
    name={\ensuremath{ \xi }},  
    description={space variable} }

\newglossaryentry{xii}{type=symbols,
    name={\ensuremath{ \xi_i }},    
    description={discretized space variable} }

\newglossaryentry{f}{type=symbols,
    name={\ensuremath{ f }},    
    description={function of space variable} }

\newglossaryentry{fbis}{type=symbols,
    name={\ensuremath{ f }},    
    description={another function of space variable} }

\newglossaryentry{fi}{type=symbols,
    name={\ensuremath{ f_i }},  
    description={discretized function} }

\begin{document}
    A document that contains \gls{f}, \gls{xi}, \gls{fi} and \gls{xii},  but also a second \gls{fbis}. 

    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This ensures distinct sort values, which prevents xindy from merging the entries with duplicate names.

[image: image of list of symbols]

Note that xindy strips all control sequences from the sort value so `\ensuremath{ \xi }` changes into a space. (If you had `\ensuremath{\xi}` instead, you'd get an error without this redefinition of `\glsprestandardsort` because the sort value would become an empty string which xindy doesn't permit.) In this case, the description has been concatenated so the sort value for the `xi` entry becomes a space character followed by "space variable", whereas the `xii` entry becomes "i discretized space variable" (again the `\xi` is stripped but the `i` from the subscript remains). This is why the `xi` term ends up at the end of the list. If you strip all the leading and trailing spaces from the argument of each `\ensuremath`, you get a different order (`f_i` ends up before `f`).

If you want to consider switching from xindy to [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls), it's much easier to provide fallback behaviour for duplicate sort values (and commands like `\xi` are recognised as mathematical Greek letters instead of being discarded).

File `symbols.bib`:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@symbol{xi,
  name = {\ensuremath{ \xi }},
  description = {space variable}
}

@symbol{xii,
  name = {\ensuremath{ \xi_i }},
  description = {discretized space variable}
}

@symbol{f,
  name = {\ensuremath{ f }},
  description = {function of space variable}
}

@symbol{fbis,
  name = {\ensuremath{ f }},
  description = {another function of space variable}
}

@symbol{fb,
  name = {\ensuremath{ f_b }},
  description = {another function}
}

@symbol{fi,
  name = {\ensuremath{ f_i }},
  description = {discretized function}
}
```

Main document file:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nomain,record]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{Nomenclature}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
   src={symbols}, % entries in symbols.bib
   symbol-sort-fallback=name,% sort @symbol entries by name field
   identical-sort-action=description,% sort by description if sort value identical
   type=symbols,% put these entries in the symbols glossary
   save-locations=false% location list not needed
]

\begin{document}
    A document that contains \gls{f}, \gls{xi}, \gls{fi} and
\gls{xii},  but also a second \gls{fbis}.

    \printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

This lists Greek letters after Latin:

[image: image of symbol list]